# Find function limit

Tags: limits

I have a problem with solving following limit. 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow 0}(x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}$$
I tried to estimate it let :$$z=max(x^2,y^2)$$
$$z^{z}\le(x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}\le (2z)^{z^2}$$
Using 3 function statment i get that limit is 1 where Wolfram shows 0. Will be more than glad for help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Convert to polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, $$(r^2)^{r^4\cdot cos^2a\cdot sin^2a}=r^{(r^4\cdot sin^22a)/2}$$
$$0\le lnr^{(r^4\cdot sin^22a)/2}=\frac{1}{2}(r^4\cdot sin^22a)\cdot lnr\le\frac{1}{2}(r^4)\cdot lnr\rightarrow0$$ ?
If i am not mistaken same as before.My previous estimation was bad?